# Cannot assign value of type 'Any' to type 'String?'

Tags: ios, swift, soap

I received `Cannot assign value of  type 'Any' to type 'String?'`
when i pass the `posts` value to `cell.textLabel?.text`, i have received response from the soap service and i add to posts `posts.add(elements)`.
And also i want to pass that `Posts` to my `secondViewController` please help, Thankyou

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController ,XMLParserDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate, NSURLConnectionDelegate, UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var firstName: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var lastName: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    var parser = XMLParser()

    var posts = NSMutableArray()

    var elements = NSMutableDictionary()
    var element = NSString()
    var title1 = NSMutableString()
    var date = NSMutableString()

     var xmlData = NSMutableData()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = UITableViewCell()

        cell.textLabel?.text = posts[indexPath.row] // Cannot assign value of  type 'Any' to type 'String?'

        print(indexPath.row)
        return cell
    }

    func beginParsing()
    {
        posts = []
        parser = (XMLParser(data:xmlData as Data))
        parser.delegate = self
        parser.parse()
        //tbData!.reloadData()

        for element in posts {
            print(element)
        }
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String])
    {
        element = elementName as NSString

        if (elementName as NSString).isEqual(to: "response")
        {
            elements = NSMutableDictionary()
            elements = [:]
            title1 = NSMutableString()
            title1 = ""
            date = NSMutableString()
            date = ""

        }
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String)
    {


       // let data = string.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines).uppercased()

       // let str = data.replacingOccurrences(of: "<[^>]+>", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)

        if element.isEqual(to: "status")
        {
                 title1.append(string)

         }
        else if element.isEqual(to: "message") {
            date.append(string)
        }
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?)
    {
        if (elementName as NSString).isEqual(to: "response")
        {

            if !title1.isEqual(nil) {
                elements.setObject(title1, forKey: "status" as NSCopying)
            }
            if !date.isEqual(nil) {
                elements.setObject(date, forKey: "message" as NSCopying)
            }
            posts.add(elements)
        }
    }


    @IBAction func invoke(_ sender: Any) {

        let firstNmaeValue = firstName.text
        let lastNameValue = lastName.text

        let is_SoapMessage  = String  (format :"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><doRegisterUser soapenv:encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'><firstNameValue>\(firstNmaeValue)</firstNameValue><lastNameValue>\(lastNameValue)</lastNameValue></doRegisterUser></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>")

        let is_URL: String = "http://192.168.43.23/app/app/service/nm.php?wsdl"

        let lobj_Request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: is_URL)! as URL)
        let session = URLSession.shared

        lobj_Request.httpMethod = "POST"
        lobj_Request.httpBody = is_SoapMessage.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        lobj_Request.addValue("192.168.43.23", forHTTPHeaderField: "Host")

        lobj_Request.addValue("text/xml; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        lobj_Request.addValue(String (is_SoapMessage), forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")

        lobj_Request.addValue("http://192.168.43.23/app/app/service/nm.php/doRegisterUser", forHTTPHeaderField: "SOAPAction")

        let task = session.dataTask(with: lobj_Request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

            print("response = \(response)")




             let xmlData = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)


            self.xmlData = NSMutableData(data: data!)

            print("Body: \(xmlData)")

            self.beginParsing()

           print("Status is = \(self.title1)")

            print("Message is = \(self.date)")

            if error != nil
            {
                print("Error: ")
            }

        })
        task.resume()

    }

}
```

Comment: Your `posts` array is an `NSMultableArray` of unspecified type so its elements will be of type `Any`, therefore, you need to cast it to string first, and then set it.

Comment: If you are sure `posts[indexPath.row]` returns `String` then try `posts[indexPath.row] as? String ?? ""`

Comment: @Dharmesh Kheni , @ Xcoder123 Thankyou for help, Any idea how can i print this `posts` in tableView?

Comment: Where you want to print it?

Comment: @Dharmesh Kheni In my storyboard I have two text field `firstName` & `lastName` then Button and under that i have created tableView. i have got tis response `{
    message = Welcome;
    status = "User registration successful";
}` i want to print that in my table view

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to cast the `Any` to a `String`..

```
cell.textLabel?.text = posts[indexPath.row] as? String
```

Comment: `cell.textLabel?.text = posts[indexPath.row] as? String ?? "other string"` may be better for error handling

Comment: @Callam , Thank you  its fixed.

Comment: @callam But my response its not print in my tableView, can you give me any idea about that please

Comment: @ViralRathod try to `print(posts[indexPath.row]) `in cell and tell the response

Comment: @Callam No Nothing happend

Comment: Then your function is not called at all

Comment: Hmm, but i can print `posts` i received response { message = Welcome; status = "User registration successful"; } i want to print that in my table view