# How can i access a field in a randomly generated auto id IN XCODE FIRESTORE

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to set a labels text to the value stored under my firstname and lastname field stored under a randomly generated document id of users. Ive believe my userDoc object is accessing the correct autoID but i dont know how to pull that data out and then set it to the label text. Below is y code and a picture of my firestore database. I am getting an error while trying this approach of cannot assign value of type any? to type string?on my userDoc.value. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkRYf.png)

```
if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
        let userid = user.uid
        let db = Firestore.firestore()

        //db.collection("users").getDocuments(completion: <#T##FIRQuerySnapshotBlock##FIRQuerySnapshotBlock##(QuerySnapshot?, Error?) -> Void#>)
        name.text = user.email
        status.text = user.displayName
        //status.text = user.value(forKey: "firstname") as? String
        let userDoc = db.collection("users").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: userid)
        status.text = userDoc.value(forKeyPath: "firstname")
    }
```

Comment: What will `userDoc.value(forKeyPath: "firstname")` output if you log it? Try casting it to string as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42153583/12232507) suggests.

Comment: @EmilGi ive tried casting it as a string but how do i go about logging it? Im getting this error just by setting the declaration Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<FIRDocumentReference 0x6000000ed110> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key firstname.'

Comment: I am not sure about how you get the data, check [the official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#source_options) on how to get data with Swift and try to  tweak your code accordingly.